# how to have a particular day of a date field in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a date field which has a config of `2019-07-26T16:04:56.853Z` this kind in my data when i have given add field with `+EEEE`, it is giving the day of timestamp , but not the required output.

```
add_field => {"[weekday]" => "%{+EEEEE}"}
```

I need that the output of the date field of `2019-07-26T16:04:56.853Z`gives friday but it is giving the timestamp day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the string "2019-07-26T16:04:56.853Z" in a field called [date] then this will set [dayOfWeek] to Friday

```
    mutate { gsub => [ "Date", "Z$", "" ] }
    date { match => [ "date", ISO8601 ] target => "[@metadata][date]" }
    ruby { code => '
        t = Time.at(event.get("[@metadata][date]").to_i)
        d = DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
        event.set("dayOfWeek", d.strftime("%A"))
    ' }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code ,I'll let you about the working of the code

Comment: Hi , The code you sent is working but it's giving thursday, instead of friday to the date   2019-07-26

Comment: I get "Friday' from that code. I wonder if this is a timezone issue.

Comment: Hi ,i have given a image there you can see the day of week as thursday.

Comment: Did you change "date" in the date filter to "Date" to match your data? If not it is telling you that 1970/01/01 was a Thursday. To avoid the timezone problem you can use mutate to remove the Z

Comment: I have changed that and after it has given "Friday".   Thank You so such that helped me a lot.